# Is there a way of manually removing useless words from a proportion table after extracting text from a character string?

Tags: r, text, data-cleaning

## Text Extraction Problem:

Not sure who here can help me with this, but I'm running into a problem trying to split this song into a bunch of separable Chinese characters. I first loaded the lyrics into a variable, split by no spaces, sorted them, then put them into a proportion table:

```
cj <- "我曾經問個不休 你何時跟我走
可你卻總是笑我 一無所有
我要給你我的追求 還有我的自由
可你卻總是笑我 一無所有
噢 你何時跟我走
噢 你何時跟我走
腳下這地在走 身邊那水在流
可你卻總是笑我 一無所有
為何你總笑個沒夠 為何我總要追求
難道在你面前 我永遠是一無所有
噢 你何時跟我走
噢 你何時跟我走
（腳下這地在走 身邊那水在流）
（腳下這地在走 身邊那水在流）
告訴你我等了很久 告訴你我最後的要求
我要抓起你的雙手 你這就跟我走
這時你的手在顫抖 這時你的淚在流
莫非你是正在告訴我 你愛我一無所有
噢 你這就跟我走
噢 你這就跟我走
（腳下這地在走 身邊那水在流）
（腳下這地在走 身邊那水在流）
噢 你這就跟我走
噢 你這就跟我走
噢 你這就跟我走
噢 你這就跟我走"

cj_split <- strsplit(x=cj,
         fixed=T,
         split = "")
cj_split <- sort(table(cj_split),
                 decreasing = T)
cj_props <- sort(prop.table(cj_split))
cj_props
```

This gives me this proportion table that includes empty spaces and non values at the end of the table like "\n" which I dont need:

```
> cj_props
cj_split
         愛          不          曾          顫          道          等          抖          非 
0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 
         給          夠          還          很          後          經          久          了 
0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 
         淚          沒          面          莫          難          起          前          雙 
0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 
         問          休          永          由          遠          正          抓          自 
0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 0.002941176 
         最          個          手          為          追          告          可          求 
0.002941176 0.005882353 0.005882353 0.005882353 0.005882353 0.008823529 0.008823529 0.008823529 
         卻          訴          （          ）          笑          要          邊          地 
0.008823529 0.008823529 0.011764706 0.011764706 0.011764706 0.011764706 0.014705882 0.014705882 
         腳          那          身          是          水          所          無          下 
0.014705882 0.014705882 0.014705882 0.014705882 0.014705882 0.014705882 0.014705882 0.014705882 
         一          總          的          流          有          何          就          時 
0.014705882 0.014705882 0.017647059 0.017647059 0.017647059 0.020588235 0.020588235 0.020588235 
         噢          跟          在          這          走          \n          你             
0.029411765 0.035294118 0.041176471 0.041176471 0.050000000 0.073529412 0.073529412 0.076470588 
         我 
0.076470588
```

Is there a way to remove these before creating a data frame with them? I want to retain the true percentages rather than tidying it up with dplyr and losing the actual percentages of real characters.

## Edit:

I discovered another function that at least rids me of one problem. If I use the following code:

```
cj <- chartr(x=cj,
   old = "\n",
   new = " ")
```

That at least gets rid of the symbols. Still need to figure out how to get rid of the space counts though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out via a rather roundabout way. Before creating my tables, I used the following code to remove all of the odd characters...the issue was that RStudio treats alphabetic parentheses and Sinitic parentheses (in my case Chinese) differently, so you have to filter them out, as they create extra spaces as well:

```
# Replace spaces and parentheses:
cj <- gsub( pattern = "\n", 
           replacement = "", 
           x = cj, 
           fixed = TRUE )
cj <- gsub(pattern = " ",
     replacement = "",
     x=cj,
     fixed = TRUE)
cj <- gsub(pattern = "（",
           replacement = "",
           x=cj,
           fixed = TRUE)
cj <- gsub(pattern = "）",
           replacement = "",
           x=cj,
           fixed=TRUE)
```

This is what the table looks like now, free of the unnecessary characters:

```
         我          你          走          在          這          跟          噢          何 
0.092526690 0.088967972 0.060498221 0.049822064 0.049822064 0.042704626 0.035587189 0.024911032 
         就          時          的          流          有          邊          地          腳 
0.024911032 0.024911032 0.021352313 0.021352313 0.021352313 0.017793594 0.017793594 0.017793594 
         那          身          是          水          所          無          下          一 
0.017793594 0.017793594 0.017793594 0.017793594 0.017793594 0.017793594 0.017793594 0.017793594 
         總          笑          要          告          可          求          卻          訴 
0.017793594 0.014234875 0.014234875 0.010676157 0.010676157 0.010676157 0.010676157 0.010676157 
         個          手          為          追          愛          不          曾          顫 
0.007117438 0.007117438 0.007117438 0.007117438 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 
         道          等          抖          非          給          夠          還          很 
0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 
         後          經          久          了          淚          沒          面          莫 
0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 
         難          起          前          雙          問          休          永          由 
0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 
         遠          正          抓          自          最 
0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719 0.003558719
```

If anybody has a faster alternative, I'd be happy to hear it. For now this works.